# How to comment and Like on friends wall through FBGraph API?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to comment and Like on friends wall through FBGraph API?

Comment: You've read the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/? Can you be more specific about which part you're looking for more info on, and have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation with examples on how to do this is at at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/.

You need to

- authenticate (get an access token)
- know your friend's ID
- do an HTTP POST to the right URL to create posts or like existing posts.

The section labelled "Publishing" on the aforelinked documentation page shows how to do this.